# Identifying the module causing high CPU in w3wp

Tags: windows, performance, iis, server, sitecore8

I'm trying to find the cause of high CPU situations on an IIS web server (running Sitecore). Task Manager shows that w3wp is the cause. There are DLLs running under w3wp. I assume one of those is the culprit. Performance Profiler in Visual Studio 2019 shows CPU usage by Module (see image). Is there a tool that can get this for me on a server that doesn't have Visual Studio installed? If the data exists in Process Explorer, Performance Monitor or Process Monitor I can’t find it.

[image]

(Please do not mark this as a duplicate unless the duplicate specifies how to see the CPU usage of a module beneath w3wp.)

Comment: Any good enough .NET performance profiler gives you the same.

Comment: It sounds like you have personal experience with this. Which one would you recommend?

Comment: you could use Debug Diagnostics 1.2 and Performance Monitor to troubleshoot the high CPU usage issue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/performance-issues/troubleshooting-high-cpu-in-an-iis-7x-application-pool

Comment: I've tried DebugDiag in the last couple of days. Just downloaded the latest version now (2.3.0.37). I don't see an Advanced tab and none of the dumps contain CPU % data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using PerfView provided by MS. Full CPU loading from all threads and built-in loading of MS modules.